# Somebody commented or answered and I was notified but I don't see it

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, notifications

I asked a question on the Physical Fitness SE about integrating bodyweight exercises with 5K training and I also installed the Stack Exchange app on my phone.

I saw a notification on my phone that had the Stack Exchange symbol and said "Have you tried a bodyweight full body workout?" and there was more to it so I tapped the notification to go to the Stack Exchange app and unfortunately, I saw nothing on the app. I went to the site, same thing.

Now I have waited for hours and I still don't see the comment or answer that I got notified of on my phone.

Why is this? Did the comment or answer get deleted when I tapped the notification?

Comment: Yeah, it probably got deleted.

Answer (score 7):

The notifications pushed to your phone are there until you actually visit the app.

This is something I've noticed in the years that I've used it (the iOS version, though). On the site, if a comment is deleted, the notification goes away but I think there's no way for them to retract the notification once it's on your phone. And, as you say, you can't see them in your inbox on either the app or the full site.

I've often found this frustrating because sometimes the notifications you get aren't very nice but there's no way to figure out where they came from because they're gone (if you don't know which site/post they were made on)... but c'est la vie.

If you want more information about whether it was an answer or a comment deleted (my bet's on the latter), you can ask on the [Physical Fitness SE's child meta site](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/) and one of the mods there can tell you which it was and possibly even explain why it was removed.